# How to pass NUMBER_LIST_TYPE IN parameter to ORACLE stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
Create or replace procedure readEmpDetails (empRowList NUMBER_LIST_TYPE, 
                                            created_by VARCHAR2, 
                                            accessid NUMBER )
is
```

How can I pass parameter for NUMBER_LIST_TYPE:

```
begin  readEmpDetails([124, 155, 147], '100', 2);  end;
```

I want to pass parameter like above in Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the below steps:

```
create or replace type T_array_readEmpDetails AS VARRAY(10) of number(4)
/

Create or replace procedure readEmpDetails (t_ar T_array_readEmpDetails, 
                                            created_by VARCHAR2, 
                                            accessid NUMBER )
is
begin
      FOR i IN 1..t_ar.count LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(t_ar(i));
     END LOOP;
end;
/
 DECLARE
      v T_array_readEmpDetails;
    BEGIN
      v := T_array_readEmpDetails();
      v.EXTEND(3);
      v(1) := 124;
      v(2) := 155;
      v(3) := 147;
      readEmpDetails(v,'A',1);
    END;
/
```

Comment: Why `EXTEND(4)` and not `EXTEND(3)`? You will be passing a 4th element with the value `NULL`.

Comment: @MT0 the above was a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

If NUMBER_LIST_TYPE is a valid oracle type, you pass it as `NUMBER_LIST_TYPE(124, 155, 147)`.
Then you are creating an instance of the type with 3 Elements "on the fly".